# How to disable Android Google Smart Lock feature in Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, google-smartlockpasswords

I want to disable Google Smart Lock offer in login edittext in my application. Is there any way to do it for a specific application or even specific views? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add textNoSuggestions?

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```